# How to create Correlation Heat Map of All Measure in Tableau?

Tags: pandas, tableau-api, heatmap, tableau-desktop, pearson-correlation

I have Query with 10 Measures I am able to draw correlation heat map in Python using below?

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib as mt

df = pd.read_sql('select statement')
sn.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True)
mt.pyplot.show()

How can I make similar correlation heat map in Tableau?

Comment: can you show an example of the output you're seeking, instead of just showing your Python code?

Answer (score 2):

The general way to make a heatmap in Tableau is to put a discrete field on rows and a discrete field on columns. Select the square mark type. Under Format, make a square cell size, and adjust the cell size to be as large as you prefer.

Then put a continuous field on the color shelf. Click on the color button to choose the color palette you like, and possibly turn on a border. Click on the size button to adjust the mark size to match the cell size.

There are a lot of good examples on Tableau Public.
https://public.tableau.com/app/search/vizzes/correlation%20matrix